# Including json retrieved data persistently across multiple pages in a site... best practice?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jsp

On this site each page is made up of multiple .jsp files. There is a main page that contains the bulk of the page content but then navigation is handled by nav.jsp, top title section is handled by top-section.jsp, footer.jsp, etc.

The content of the pages is populated by data retrieved via json from a middle ware server. For the main pages (i.e. the section of the page that contains the bulk of the page specific data) data is retrieved by an ajax call that uses the logged in users id to get what it needs.

My question, how do I include some retrieved data in the, say, top-section.jsp. This page is simply (and I'm using hard coded data here but in reality this data should be specific to the logged in user):

```
<div id="userinfo">Harald Niven | <a href="nivenhelp?id=12345">Help</a></div>
```

This little bit is included in each page so I would like to grab the name ("Harald Niven" and the help url) once and then use it across every page in the site. Assuming that communication with the middle ware is via ajax calls that return json, what would be the best way to do this?

When I load data for each page it is simple, I have a custom js file for that page that grabs the needed data, however, this top section never changes so it seems wasteful to do an ajax request and parse out the response every time... **how can I grab this once and persist it across the entire time the user is logged in?**

Edit: sessions/cookies are out due to requirements of this app and I cannot write to the database... only read from it in a very restricted manner (any requests by the front end folks for accessing the database require a huge pain in the butt amount of approval and explanation so if I can avoid going this route I want to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rg88 ,

You need to implement the session management,  ideally in all the websites people use a different database to track the users.

So you need to store the user login info retrived from json object in a track database along with sessionID.

Otherwise if you want to go for simple approach , you can store it in the cookies which is not a good practice.

Comment: Both sessions and cookies are not usable with this app and I do not have access to save/update to the database... only retrieve and even that is very limited.

Comment: there is one more option is store the values in a hidden div?? for example header or footer might be common to all pages right ,store the values in some hidden div or hidden span and retrieve where ever you want.

Comment: @rg88 , cookies should be ok right , you can write and read from your javascript and expire them once the session is over.

Comment: @rg88 do you agree with any of the above...approaches??

Comment: I like the idea of sticking the data into a dom element.